# Can I use RSA to sign a python class object?

Tags: python, rsa, sign

I'm creating an election system that utilizes blockchain for record keeping. I defined the block in the following class:

```
 class Block:
    def __init__(self, machine_id, timestamp, data, previous_hash):
        self.machine_id = machine_id
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.data = data
        self.previous_hash = previous_hash
        self.hash = self.hash_block()

    # Function to create hash of proposed block
    def hash_block(self):
        sha = hasher.sha256()
        sha.update((str(self.machine_id) + str(self.timestamp) + str(self.data) + str(self.previous_hash)).encode("utf-8"))
        return sha.hexdigest()
```

Using sockets, I want a node to broadcast their proposed blocks across all nodes to append to their local blockchain. Before broadcasting, I'm looking to have the node sign their block with their private key. Each node will have record of all other nodes public key in order to verify the signature. Is there a way of signing a class object such as a block rather than a simple string message?

Comment: This may help, [Let’s Build the Tiniest Blockchain](https://medium.com/crypto-currently/lets-build-the-tiniest-blockchain-e70965a248b) (off site)

Comment: @miraculixx I've actually read that and based my blockchain structure off of that. However, it doesn't have anything about digitally signing blocks to send to other nodes. I'm creating a permissioned blockchain rather than a public blockchain, so rather than mining to verify the blocks, I just have authorized nodes sign blocks to propose

Comment: You have to pick a representation of your block for RSA to work with because RSA works with integers. The block hash itself would be a good candidate, since it's fixed-length and mitigates some types of attacks.

Comment: @Blender That's actually a great point that you made. The Hash itself is a fixed length and is a representation of the block itself. Thank you so much!